# Не могу вывести статью на той же странице при клике на ссылке в sidebar?

Tags: php, javascript, css

Задача: При клике на ссылке "aerius" "вывести статью(aerius.html) в div "content" не переходя на новую страницу но ничего не выводится.
Файл aerius.html  находится в каталоге pages.

**HTML**

```
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Hello World</title>

 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">


 </head>



<body>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>

  <div id="header">
   <img src="images/alphasoft.png" alt="picture" height="60px">

   <div id=reg_auth>
        <a href="" title="enter your account">
            <div id="btn">
                შესვლა
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="" title="регистрация на сайте">        
            <div id="btn">
                регистрация
            </div>  
        </a>

   </div>   
  </div>

  <div id="nav">
      <ul class="nav_main_ul">
        <li><a href="">Main</a>
          <ul class="submenu"> 
            <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link 4</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li> <a href="#">News</a>
          <ul class="submenu"> 
            <li><a href="#">link 5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link 6</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link 7</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link 8</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link 9</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link 10</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>  
        <li><a href="#">About us</a>
          <ul class="submenu"> 
            <li><a href="#">link 5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link 6</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link 7</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link 8</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link 9</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link 10</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>  
        <li><a href="#">Gallery</a>
          <ul class="submenu"> 
            <li><a href="#">link 5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link 6</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link 7</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link 8</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link 9</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link 10</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>  
        <li><a href="#">Contacts</a>
          <ul class="submenu"> 
            <li><a href="#">link 5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link 6</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link 7</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link 8</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link 9</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link 10</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>   
      </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="sidebar">
    <ul class="menu">
        <li class="menu_list"><a href="">antiallergics</a>
          <ul class="menu_drop"> 
            <li><a class="file-link" title="aerius" href="#erius">erius</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">claritine</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">ketotifen</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">suprastin</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">dimedrol</a></li>   
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">antihelminthics</a></li>  
        <li class="menu_list"><a href="#">antibiotics</a>
          <ul class="menu_drop"> 
            <li><a href="#">ceftriaqsone</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">amoxicillin</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Oxitetracicline</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">tilozine</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">penstrep</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>  
        <li><a href="#">nootropics</a></li>  
        <li class="menu_list"><a href="#">nonsteroids</a>
          <ul class="menu_drop"> 
            <li><a href="#">movalis</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">nimesil</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">dicloberl</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">voltaren</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">aspirin</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>   
      </ul>
  </div>    

  <div id="content">
    <br />

    <form action="goods.php" method="post" style="margin-left:20px;"> 
    <h3>name</h3><br />
    <input type="text" name="goods"<br/> 
    <input type="submit" name="btn_select" value="select">
    <input type="submit" name="btn_insert" value="insert">
    </form> 

  </div>

  <div id="footer"></div>

 <?php
 include "connect_db.php";
 ?>

  <script src="js/main.js"></script>

 </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style:none;
}
 html, body {
    height: 100%;  
}    
#header{
    left:0; top:0; 
    height:70px;
    width:100%;
    background:yellow;
}
#reg_auth{
    float:right;
    width:20%;
}
#reg_auth a{
    color:green;
}
#reg_auth a:hover #btn{
    border-bottom:2px solid rgba(217,91,72,1);
    margin-top:7px;
}
#reg_auth a:active #btn{
    border-bottom:0;
    margin-top:9px;
}
#btn{
    float:right;
    margin-right:3%;
    margin-top:5px;
    border-radius:5px;
    padding:5px 9px;
    font-size:1em;
    background-color: #00004d;
    text-shadow:#454545 0 0 2px;
    border-bottom: 4px solid rgba(217, 91, 72, 1);

}
#content {
    position:absolute;
    left:200px; top:120px; bottom: 0; right:0;
    height:740px; 
    background:white;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
#sidebar {
    position:absolute;
    left:0; top:120px; bottom: 0;
    height:740px; 
    width: 200px;
    background-color:#00004d;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
#footer {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #00004d; 
    bottom:0;
    height:40px;
}
#nav{
    left:0; top:120px;
    background-color: #00004d;
    width: 100%;
}
.nav_main_ul{
    position:relative;
    margin: 0px 0 0 200px; 
}
#nav ul{ 
    height:50px;
    list-style:none;
    background-color: #00004d;  
}   
#nav li{
    display:block;
    float:left;
    font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:20px;
    position:relative; 
}
#nav li a{
    color:#fff;  
    display:block;
    height:50px;
    padding:0 10px;
    text-decoration:none;
    line-height:50px;
}
.nav_main_ul li a:hover{
    background:#000080;  /*blue*/
}
.submenu{
    position:absolute; 
/*  top:120px;  */
    width:250px;
}
.submenu li{
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    background:#00004d;
}
.submenu li a{
    line-height:50px;
    height:50px;
    transition: background 0.5s;
} 
.submenu li a:hover{
    background-color:red;
}
li:hover .submenu li{
    display:block;
    z-index: 100; 
}
.menu a{
    text-decoration:none;  
    background: #00004d; 
    color:#fff;
    padding:10px;
    display:block;
    border-bottom:1px solid #666;
    transition:0.5s all;
}
.menu a:hover{
    background:#666;
    padding: 10px 0 10px 20px; 
}
/*вспливающее меню*/
.menu_list{
position:relative;
z-index:9999;
}
.menu_drop{
position:absolute;
width:100%;
left:100%;
top:-9999em;
opacity:0; 
border-left:10px solid transparent;
transition:0.5s opacity; 
}
.menu_list:hover .menu_drop{
opacity:1;
top:0; 
}  

 .menu_list:after{
    content:" ";
    position:absolute;
    border:5px solid; 
    border-color:transparent transparent transparent #eee; 
    top:1em;
    right:0.7em; 
    transition:0.5s;
}
.menu_list:hover::after{ 
    transform:scalex(-1); 
}
```

**Main.js**

```
$(function() {

    $('a.file-link').on('click', function() {
        var href = 'pages/' + $(this).attr('title') + '.html';
        $('.content').load(href);
    });

})
```

А вот такой код правильно работает:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Some project</title>
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <ul>
          <li><a class="file-link" title="aerius" href="#eriusi">erius</a></li>
          <li><a class="file-link" title="second" href="#second file name">second file</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="content"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- main -->
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Style.css**

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 900px;
  margin: auto;
}

ul {
  width: 20%;
  background: #0ca;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

a:hover {
  background: #0ee;
}

.content {
  background: #ccc;
  min-height: 100px;
}

.aerius p {
  color: blue;
}

.second p {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: blue;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Обратите внимание на `$('.content')`. Точка в начале означает, что вы выбираете класс. В примере, который работает, у вас `<div class="content"></div>` (вы присваиваете блоку класс), а в том, который не работает – `<div id="content">` (вы присваиваете блоку id).

Чтобы выбрать id, вам нужно загружать в `$('#content')` – знак `#` выбирает id.

Comment: точно! спасибо вам. Сколько искал :)